# How to Catch Last Widget box From Same Widget Area?

Tags: widgets, sidebar

is there any Way to Catch Last widget box or div from same widget area?? i mean i have 4 widgets in footer widget area but due to design issue my 3rd widget box style+width is different.so i want to add extra class to 3rd box container using php.is there any way to do that? please reply.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code in your functions.php file of the theme directory. Replace widget name "Home Widget Area" with your widget's name

```
    /*=============WIDGETs CSS CLASS CONTROLLER==============*/
    $GLOBALS['my_widget_num']=1;
    function edei_widget_class_adder($params){
    if( $params[0]['name']=='Home Widget Area' ){
        $GLOBALS['my_widget_num']++;
        if( ($GLOBALS['my_widget_num']%4)==0 ){
            $params[0]['before_widget'] = str_replace('class="', 'class="marginAdjust ', $params[0]['before_widget']);
        }
    }

    //print_r($params);
    return $params;
}
add_filter('dynamic_sidebar_params','edei_widget_class_adder');

function edei_widget_counter_reset($sidebars_widgets) {
   $GLOBALS['my_widget_num'] = 1;
   return $sidebars_widgets;
}
add_filter('sidebars_widgets','edei_widget_counter_reset');
```

Comment: This wont work as there's a bracket too much.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in Worpdress every widget has a unique id of the form "widget_type-xx" where widget_type is the widget internal name, and xx is a progressive number. 
I think you may use that id to apply custom css rules, and you don't really need to add a class via php, unless that widget will be replaced in future (the id would change in that case).